# android wear: hide top empty region

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

i write an app for a google watch and use the WearableListView inside one of the fragments.

**layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0sp">

    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but there is always this top empty region on the top of the list, taking away half of the space of the screen. how can i hide it? or if this is not possible, how can i change the height of it?